# unable to change the value of an XML tag

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

Here's the XML:

```
<PolicyChangeSet schemaVersion="2.1" username="" description="">
    <Attachment name="" contentType="">
        <Description/>
        <Location></Location>
    </Attachment>
</PolicyChangeSet>
```

I'm just trying to add the value "XXX" between the "location" tag.

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
    string newValue = string.Empty;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.Load(AppVars.pxCentralXMLPayloadFilePath);
    node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/PolicyChangeSet/Attachment/location");

    node.InnerText = "XXX";

    xmlDoc.Save(AppVars.pxCentralXMLPayloadFilePath);
```

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> doc.Save(@"XML FILE PATH"); //This will save the changes to the file.

Comment: sorry, saving the file is in my original code. I updated the question. I still get a null exception at node.InnerText = "XXX";.

Answer (score 0):

Please use iteration through [ChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) of `XmlDocument` - as described in [walkthrough](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233) from MS Support site. According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) of `SelectSingleNode()` method:

> The XmlNode should not be expected to be connected "live" to the XML
>   document. That is, changes that appear in the XML document may not
>   appear in the XmlNode, and vice versa.

Comment: sorry, saving the file is in my original code. I updated the question. I still get a null exception at node.InnerText = "XXX";.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was CASE SENSITIVITY.

Comment: Has found the reason - modifications does not have effect as result of `SelectSingleNode` is not expected to be connected with source `XmlDocument` - please see [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11904649/894174).